# Using a Button click to execute ASP.net C# gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

It seems like this would be simple, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how it would work.

I have a `gridview`.

I have a standard button.

How do I use the button click to display the gridview?

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the definition of "execute" the gridview?

Comment: sorry, poor word choice, I think. I want to use the button click to display the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

This is a brief example from the MSDN page: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx)

You might to add an `asp:TemplateField` inside your `GridView` and through the CommandArgument property in the Button, set the current row index.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" 
      CommandName="AddToCart" 
CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
      Text="Add to Cart" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And in your code, in the `RowCommand` event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart") {
        // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
        // CommandArgument property.
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
        // from the Rows collection.
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

        // Add code here to add the item to the shopping cart.
    }
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: It's all good guys. I figured out how to do what I wanted. I was trying to over think it. I simply set GridView.Visible to "false" and then used the button click event to make it visible again.